# error: ‘class::class()’ is private within this context

Tags: c++, arrays, private

I've seen a few answers on this topic, but to my knowledge they don't quite answer the problem I'm getting. Here is my paraphrased code:

```
using namespace std;

class classname
{
private:
    int foo;

    classname();
};

classname::classname()
{
    //dostuff
}
  
int main(){
    classname arr[5];
}
```

The code errors:

> error: ‘classname::classname()’ is private within this context

My best guess is that `private:` bled into my constructor definition. How do I stop this?

Comment: When you wrtie `private:`, it has effect on every member declared later until you write another access specifier.

Comment: *My best guess is that private: bled into my constructor definition. How do I stop this?* -- The C++ book you're using should have shown `private` and `public` access specifiers within the same class.

Comment: Note: `class`es default to `private` so without an explicit `public` (or `protected`) ahead of the declaration of the constructor, the constructor will be `private`.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of any "answers" you may have encountered that would not have mentioned `public:` as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Everything after `private:` is marked as private until the end of the class is reached or another visibility token. Put your function above the `private:` or put a `public:` before the function declaration.

Comment: Oops I meant a closing brace, but that’s not accurate either. I guess I should have put the end of the class.

Comment: Fixed. For some reason it wasn't allowing me to do it from mobile.